# Maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: errors

I recently installed the Fatal Error Notify plugin on my WordPress because I had a feeling something was off.

Turns out, at least twice per day, I'm getting the following error:
Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

It isn't just one function or file running into this error, but many, including:

- wp-cron
- class-wp-hook
- wc-core-functions
- curl

I know I could increase the php max execution time, but I don't think that's best practice.

I'm not sure how to figure out what's causing these actions to be so slow, so I'm open to any troubleshooting I could do. But I'd also like confirmation on whether or not I should modify my php max execution time.

Thanks for any help!